# MS Excel Find & Match Duplicate Values & copy across Unique Identifying Number to mark Duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have two excel spreadsheets.

They are large sheets – one has approx. 8,000 rows, the other has approx. 50,000 rows.

Each row contains someone’s first name, last name and address.

In the 8k spreadsheet I have given every record a unique identifier number.

I think those £8k records all have duplicates in the 50k page. I want to find a way for excel to check and if a record has an identical last name/postcode to another record, the first record will copy the unique identifier from the £8k spreadsheet and put next to the matching record in the 50k page.

Is this possible or am I looking for a functionality that doesn’t exist?

Comment: Identical last name AND postcode, or identical last name OR postcode?

Answer (score 0):

Where columns A,B, and C are your first, last, and postcode, and column D is your unique ID, try something like:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$1$D$8000, 
MATCH(A1&B1&C1, Sheet1!$A$1$A$8000&Sheet1!$B$1$B$8000&Sheet1!$C$1$C$8000,0)),
"")
```